# sql запрос распарсить результат в List из массива стринг

Tags: java, sql, spring

собственно вот пример:

```
 List<String> list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select id from auto", String.class); - вот так мы получим список ID
```

а как мне получить список строк?  из всего запроса?
 `List<String[]> list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from auto", String[].class);` - пробывал так, говорит что типо ожидаемое значение одно а приходит  7 столбцов, но мне и надо все семь. Как получить значения всех строк и всех ячеек  из запроса? если я не знаю названия столбцов чтобы писать RowMapper ? и заранее не знаю конечное количество столбцов

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите использовать именно метод `queryForList`, то делается это примерно так:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from auto");
```

в результате чего получите список из  `Map<String, Object>` для каждой строки, где key - имя колонки, value - значение колонки для данной строки. Очевидное неудобство  - значения мапы придётся кастовать.